# How can I create a windows resource to embed in a .NET assembly, starting from text?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, version-control, resource-files

I was looking into [embedding custom version strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120936/can-i-add-custom-version-strings-to-a-net-dll) using in assemblies a while back, and one approach that the documentation suggested was to embed a windows resource.

The only way I can see to create a windows resource is to use the 'Native Resource Template', but the template is a binary file that isn't suitable for using with [subwcrev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html).  Is there a way of creating a windows resource as part of a C# project that starts with a human-editable text file, similarly to the .rc files that C++ projects use?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have VS2005 or VS2008 and are looking to create windows resources. Yes, the ".resources" files are binary, but you can create a XML file or a text file which gets converted to this binary file. Take a look at the documentation of the [ResGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1(VS.80).aspx) tool. It is available with .NET.

Comment: I have VS2008.  I can create windows resources from a text file in a C++ project, but in a C# project they're either not windows resources, or not generated from a text file.

Comment: BTW, I don't mean CLR ".resources" files, I mean windows ".res" files.

Answer (score 0):

In VisualStudio 2005 or 2008 (at least), you can add a new "Resources File" item to the project (located under "General" in the "Add new item" dialog). This is a simple XML file, which is perfectly human-editable - all within VisualStudio. I don't know how SubWCRev works, but if it manipulates text files, this should do it.

Comment: There's no option to add version resources to that, though. I don't think it compiles to a *windows* resource, but rather to some sort of dotnet resource.